# How can I refactor a method with an unknown Class as a parameter?

Tags: java, object, methods, delegates

I want to make this method reusable but I'm not sure about how to provide a parameter that will work in the following context:

- `service.getPosts() // The method called, i.e. getPosts() should vary depending on the class parameter`
- `for (Post object : postResponse.getResults()) {  // I want the Post class to come from the parameter`
- `List<Post> objects = postResponse.getResults(); // I want the class passed into this list to also come from that same parameter`

---

**Method Call:**

```
retrieveData(mCardAdapter, Post.class);
```

**Method:**

```
private void retrieveData(final CardAdapter mCardAdapter, final Class classParam) {
        RetrofitService service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(RetrofitService.class, RetrofitService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
        service.getPosts()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<PostResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public final void onCompleted() {
                        setRefreshingFalse();
                        Log.e("RetrofitService", "Retrofit Request Completed!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public final void onError(Throwable e) {
                        setRefreshingFalse();
                        Log.e("RetrofitService", e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public final void onNext(PostResponse postResponse) {
                        if (postResponse != null) {
                            Log.e("RetrofitService", "Returned objects: " + postResponse.getResults());

                            for (Post object : postResponse.getResults()) {
                                Log.e("RetrofitService", object.getObjectId() + ": " + object.getText());
                            }

                            /*for (Post post : postResponse.getResults()) {
                                mCardAdapter.addData(post);
                            }*/

                            setRefreshingFalse();

                            mCardAdapter.clear();
                            List<Post> objects = postResponse.getResults();
                            mCardAdapter.addData(objects);

                        } else {
                            Log.e("RetrofitService", "Object returned is null.");
                        }

                    }

                });
    }
```

When I pass `Class classParam`, I just get `Unkown class: 'classParam'` as an error.

**Service:**

```
public interface RetrofitService {

    String SERVICE_ENDPOINT = "https://parseapi.back4app.com";

@Headers({
            "X-Parse-Application-Id: asdf",
            "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: asdf"
    })
    @GET("/classes/Post")
    Observable<PostResponse> getPosts();

}
```

**Post Object:**

```
public class Post implements Serializable {

    private static final String CLASS_NAME = "Post";

    private String objectId;
    private String text;

    public Post() {
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return CLASS_NAME;
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

**UPDATED (According to Roman's Suggestions):**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the invocation code for `When I pass Class classParam`...?

Comment: Could you use an interface or do you not have control of the source of the classes getting passed in?

Comment: I updated my question with the POJO and Rest Interface, but I suppose my point is that I want to just able to reuse the retrieveData method with different classes so I don't have to rewrite the code.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want generic usage as it requires rewrite of code and prefer type value pair and casting?

Comment: Very simple example. Say before calling ``retrieveData(...)`` I've got a dialog with a list, i.e. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList. The tester has a list of classes that can be selected. Upon pressing on one of those classes we call ``retrieveData(...)``. If the selection was "Post", we call Post objects. If it was "Comment", etc... Could copy and paste the ``retrieveData(...)`` method 10 times but what's the fun in that? :P

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy I updated my question with screenshots of my recent attempt to implement your changes.

Comment: You need to insert `<T>` between `private` and `void` in `retrieveData` method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You did not show `PostResponse` code, but I suppose it's something like this:

```
public class PostResponse {
    private List<Post> results;

    public List<Post> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    ....
}
```

Then you could do something like this.

First, parameterize the `Response` (to be used instead of `PostResponse`):

```
public class Response<T> {
    private List<T> results;

    public List<T> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    ....
}
```

Second, change your main method signature using type parameter:

```
private <T> void retrieveData(final CardAdapter mCardAdapter, final Class<T> classParam, DataSaver<T> saver) {
...
}
```

Inside your `retrieveData()` method you use `T` instead of `Post` and `Response<T>` instead of `PostResponse`.

But you will have to also deal with

```
mCardAdapter.addData(objects);
```

Here, simple type parametrization will most likely not work. You will have to use that last parameter (`saver`) to put the results to your container:

```
saver.save(results);
```

and in your `saver` implementation you actually do

```
public void save(List<Post> posts) {
    mCardAdapter.addData(posts);
}
```

`DataSaver` would be generic as well:

```
public interface DataSaver<T> {
    void save(List<T> objects);
}
```

Comment: T can be bounded to required Type (may be parent of all values that will be passed to generic Type Parameter)  to avoid dealing with mCardAdapter.addData(objects);

Comment: Why is T unresolved everywhere? Do I need to import something? Btw spot on with the PostResponse class.

Comment: Ah looks like RetrofitService on its own won't accept the parameterization. Requires overriding the superclass.

Comment: `T` is not a class itself, it is a type parameter; it is 'declared' in angle brackets. You don't need to import it. When you write `retrieveData(mCardAdapter, Post.class, new PostDataSaver()` where `PostDataSaver implements DataSaver<Post>`, `T` becomes `Post` in this particular invocation.

Comment: When I call ``retrieveData(mCardAdapter, Post.class, new PostDataSaver());`` it wants my retrieveData method to look like this: ``private void retrieveData(final CardAdapter mCardAdapter, final Class<Post> classParam, PostDataSaver saver) {`` instead of ``private void retrieveData(final CardAdapter mCardAdapter, final Class<T> classParam, DataSaver<T> saver) {``... and when I parameterize ``PostResponse`` the Ts are red and cannot be resolved.

Comment: Even if I pass ``final Class<Post> classParam`` directly as a paremeter I still get an unknown class for classParam in the body of my method...

Comment: Did you add `<T>` between `private` and `void` in the method header?